# Laravel: variable + parameter in view

Tags: php, laravel, variables

I want to ask if it is possible to do something like this in View in Laravel 5.2:

`<p> This is window: {{$element_ + 'window'}} </p>
 <p> This is wall: {{$element_ + 'wall'}} </p>`

The values for this variables are from $element_window, $element_wall.

Comment: Amm... [But why](http://www.reactiongifs.com/r/but-why.gif) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to dynamically name a variable.. you can do the following.

```
<p> This is window: {{ ${'element_'.'window'} }} </p>
<p> This is wall: {{ ${'element_'.'wall'} }} </p>
```

That should work.

But if just want to concatenate a string to the variable... you can use "." :-)

Comment: This is not dynamic. It is still static.

Comment: @RAVI The thing is you can use this inside a loop.. that's why it can be dynamic

Comment: Nothing to do with loop. check KidBinary's answer.

Comment: @RAVI... meaning.. using that trick.. you can call a variable from a value without hardcoding the variable's name..

Comment: @jakub .. Did my answer make sense somehow?.. :-)

Comment: @RAVI.. KidBinary's answer is the point I am saying on the last line of my answer...

Comment: @victor yes, that was what I was looking for, just concatenate strings

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of options.

First - is to use `@php` block in `.blade` file for dynamic output:

```
@php
${'window'} = ${$element_.'window'}
@endphp
```

Second is to write custom blade extension to output anything you need.

Third is to define custom method in your `Model` (if you use one).

However I should mention, that such variable assignment inside template (first option) is not recommended. It's hardly readable and could cause `Exceptions` if such dynamically created variables do not exist at some point. Not saying that this is not presentation logic.